# Import .dmp file into Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, import, sqlplus

Guys. When I tried to import a .dmp file into a fresh oracle database (sqlplus), I got this error. 
dump file "exp_tbs_gxplt01282019.dmp" may be an Data Pump export dump file

My step is:

```
SQL> create user CLIENT_TEST identified by client_test_password;
SQL> grant connect, unlimited tablespace, resource to CLIENT_TEST;
SQL> exit
```

Then,

```
imp CLIENT_TEST/client_test_password@hostname file=file_name.dmp full=y;
```

Then, I got that error mentioned. I checked out the similar posts from stackExchange and seems follow the instruction exactly the same, but no luck.

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but have you done any research about the error message you get? What did you find?

Comment: In case you were not aware: The Classic Utilities (`exp`/`imp`) and the new Data Pump Utilities (`expdp`/`impdp`) use incompatible Dump file formats.

Comment: @Michael Kutz  Thank you! I used impdp and the error is gone, but there is another error: invalid log file, I only got a .dmp file from my client and no log file. Should I create a new log file for that? or I should ask my client to provide me? P:S. I created one file named "xxxx.log", but I still got the same error: invalid log file

Comment: @mustaccio. Thanks! I solved the problem by using impdp to import the data, but I got another error which is invalid log file, should I create a log file for my dmp file?

Comment: And how would you create a log file?  That is the file to which exp/expdp/imp/impdp logs their run-time messages.  Show us the full and exact command (including the logfile specification) that you used and that generated the error.

Comment: so what you mean is that the log file will be created automatically when I run "impdp CLIENT_TEST/client_test_password@hostname file=file_name.dmp log=file_name.log full=y;" ? @EdStevens

Comment: Of course it will be created automatically when you run impdp ... with the 'log' option.  What do you think that option is for?  What do you think a _log_ file is?  If your job is failing with and error on creating the log file, it is because you have invalid file spec .. it can't create it.  In your example, you did not specify the DIRECTORY option.  Have you actually _read_ the doc on impdp?  See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/GUID-D11E340E-14C6-43B8-AB09-6335F0C1F71B.htm#SUTIL300

Comment: @ EdStevens Thanks! I read the doc and imported db successfully. The message showed  imported "XPL"."ARTICLE_USAGE_TEMP" 642.3 MB 5270266 rows. But I ran into another problem, which I cannot select * ARTICLE_USAGE_TEMP from my target table. I got the error Table does not exit. Is there any permission I should open to access the table?